# How to create multiple origins with Azure CDN Verizon Edgecast Premium?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn, edgecast

I come from AWS Cloudfront where I can create multiple origins for a given endpoint.

I can serve part of the url from one origin and part from another origin.

Is there anyway we can do with Azure CDN Verizon Edgecast Premium?

**EDIT1: (Cloudfront Example with Single Distribution)**

https://example.com/origin1/index.html <-- This is served from origin1

https://example.com/origin2/index.html <-- This is served from origin2

or like this also,

https://example.com/endpoint/index.html <-- comes from origin1

https://example.com/endpoint/index1.html <-- comes from origin2

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create mulitple origins in one Endpoint?

Comment: Let me add more documentation on how I have used in CloudFront.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT That is how modern CDN works. Not sure how to do it with Azure CDN (that costs $600 more then CloudFront). Do every possible manipulation on a given single domain.

Comment: As I known , you can only add one origin to one endpoint in Azure CDN . Azure CDN doesn't support put multiple origins in one Web Distribution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved it. Looks horrible in the modern era, but it is what it is at the time of this writing.

If you want to have multiple origins. Create one endpoint for each origin.

```
Endpoint1 --> Origin1 
Endpoint2 --> Origin2
```

Create another endpoint Endpoint to create rewrite rules to those endpoints with a rewrite rule.

```
Endpoint3/origin1 rewrite to Endpoint1
Endpoint3/origin3 rewrite to Endpoint2
```

You can create rewrite rules only to other endpoints and not to any origin.

[image]
Hope it helps.